# Form not submitting in asp.net core mvc 2.2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, form-submit, asp.net-core-2.2

I am facing a problem submitting a form in ASP.NET-core 2.2.1 MVC. I realized that the form does not submit when I click on the submit button. I have confirmed that the validation token is there and I have indicated the action path.

I generated the form from a ViewModel. Here is the view Model below

```
public class SignUpViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [Required,Display(Name ="Other Names")]
    public string Othernames { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress,Required,Display(Name ="Email Address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Phone Number"),DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber),MinLength(11,ErrorMessage ="Phone number should be a valid GSM Mobile number"),Required]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="State of Residence"),Required]
    public int? ResidenceState { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Local Government of Residence")]
    public int? ResidenceLga { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Date of Birth"),DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

The form is here

```
<form asp-action="signup" method="POST">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Surname" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Surname" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Surname" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
       <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Othernames" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Othernames" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Othernames" class="text-danger"> 
</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="EmailAddress" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="EmailAddress" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="EmailAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"> 
   </span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Gender" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="Gender" class="form-control" asp- 
     items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<Gender>()">
                <option selected="selected" value="">--Select--</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="Gender" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ResidenceState" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="ResidenceState" class="form-control" asp- 
 items="ViewBag.StateId">
  <option value="">-Select-</option>
  </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="ResidenceState" class="text-danger"> 
 </span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ResidenceLga" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="ResidenceLga" class="form-control"><option 
 value="">-Select State First-</option></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="ResidenceLga" class="text-danger"> 
</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="DateOfBirth" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="DateOfBirth" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="DateOfBirth" class="text-danger"> 
   </span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

The Controller is as follows:

```
public IActionResult Signup()
    {
        ViewData["StateId"] = new SelectList(_context.States, "Id", "Name");

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Signup(SignUpViewModel model)
    {
        if (EmailExists(model.EmailAddress))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "This email address is already registered with us.");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                Enrollee enrollee = new Enrollee {
                    Surname=model.Surname,
                    OtherNames=model.Othernames,
                    Email=model.EmailAddress,
                    Gender=model.Gender,
                    StateId=model.ResidenceState,
                    LgaId=model.ResidenceLga,
                    DateOfBirth=model.DateOfBirth
                };

                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(enrollee, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {

                    //send password the new staff's email

                    var body = "<p>Email From {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
                    var baseurl = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}{Request.PathBase}";
                    var loginurl = baseurl + "/User/Login";
                    var msg = "Congratulations! " + model.Othernames + "," + "<br />" + "You have just been registered on the eSchool portal." + "<br />" + "Use this email as your login username and the password you registered with to login to the portal:" + "<br />" + "<br />" + "Click <strong><a href='" + loginurl + "'>here</a></strong> to login" + "\r" + "\r";

                    var message = string.Format(body, "eSchool Portal", "registration@eschoolnigeria.com", msg);
                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.EmailAddress, "Registration on eSchool portal", message);

                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Signup));
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, 
error.Description);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("",e.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Something went wrong 
with the process. Please retry");
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Signup));

    }
```

I will appreciate any guide to the error making the form not to submit.

Thank you

Comment: What happens when you try to submit it? Nothing at all?

Comment: Most likely one of the values in your form isn't valid based on the validation rules defined in class `SignUpViewModel`

Comment: First, try to indicate the controller to hit (asp-controller="Home"). That should probably work. Put a breakpoint on the SignUp action to debug.

Comment: @josh have you debugged it properly to know the error? You have added lot of codes but no error message mentioned.

Comment: @TanvirArjel, Nothing just happens. I have put a break point but it is not hitting it. I dont get any error message at all. The form just reloads and that all.

Comment: @Marathon55 but I have added ModelErrors to indicate if there is any model validation issues with the data submitted

Comment: @Josh The data isn't getting submitted though so your code with ModelErrors isn't getting hit. If there is invalid data, then the validation javascript on the page (which is generated by asp net core) is preventing the data from getting submitted.

Comment: @Marathon55, if that was the the case, wouldn't the form data still remain? But the form reloads this time showing that it is not being stopped by the validation javascript

Comment: @Josh Ah, I missed your comment that says the page reloads. Here are some suggestions: Use the Tamper Chrome extension on Chrome to see what is getting posted. Also, do you know if you're hitting the [HttpPost] Signup() method? Put a breakpoint right at the beginning of it. One other thing ... it looks like you're always returning `RedirectToAction(nameof(Signup))` which would cause the behavior you're describing

Comment: @Marathon55, You are very correct. I have figured it out with your guide. The code is faulty at some point. If (ModelState.IsValid) is followed by an else statement which doesnt return view. So, instead of returning View at that point, it just returns back to the GET action and that causes that behaviour. If you can add your answer, I will accept it so it can guide others that may have such issues later on.
I really appreciate you. Thank you so much

Comment: @Josh Better give remote access with team viewer. Hope I am fixing your problem.

Comment: @TanvirArjel, Thank you for your concern and attention. We have figured out the solution. Check my previous comment.

Comment: Great to hear! Good Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `[HttpPost] Signup(...)` Action you are always returning `RedirectToAction(nameof(Signup))` which will cause you to end up back on the same page with a blank form